# What is the correct App Icon (appicon) naming convention for Xcode 9.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, appicon

I downloaded a set of 23 iOS App Icons from https://makeappicon.com that have the following filenames:

```
Icon-App-20x20@1x.png
Icon-App-20x20@2x.png
Icon-App-20x20@3x.png
Icon-App-29x29@1x.png
Icon-App-29x29@2x.png
Icon-App-29x29@3x.png
Icon-App-40x40@1x.png
Icon-App-40x40@2x.png
Icon-App-40x40@3x.png
Icon-App-57x57@1x.png
Icon-App-57x57@2x.png
Icon-App-60x60@1x.png
Icon-App-60x60@2x.png
Icon-App-60x60@3x.png
Icon-App-72x72@1x.png
Icon-App-72x72@2x.png
Icon-App-76x76@1x.png
Icon-App-76x76@2x.png
Icon-App-76x76@3x.png
Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.png
Icon-Small-50x50@1x.png
Icon-Small-50x50@2x.png
ItunesArtwork@2x.png
```

When dragging and dropping these onto a `Xcode > New Project > Single View App > Assets.xcassets > AppIcon` window all that happens is the following build warning:

> The app icon set "AppIcon" has 23 unassigned children.

This is how I have previously created App Icons, but obviously something is wrong, and I have not been able to find any helpful documentation, or StackOverflow questions or answers. What do I need to do to get Xcode to accept these pngs as the App Icon?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Don't do drag and drop add icon size wise manually

Comment: I haven't found a way to do that. What you did inspire me to try though was dragging and dropping individual pngs onto individual app icon spaces within the `Assets.xcassets > AppIcon` collection. And that seems to work

Comment: I mean, it's tedious to have to do one-at-a-time, but at least it does work

Comment: before xCode 9 drag and drop was working but in newer version it is not working. Don't know the reason

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are only 3 significant points which Xcode takes into account when it accepts **drag and drop** of the *batch* of the image files into any image asset (not only App Icon):

1. the real image width and height what Xcode gets right from the file
2. scale qualifier in the filename: `@2x`, `@3x`
3. idiom qualifier in the filename: `~ipad`, `~car`, `~mac`, `~ios-marketing`, `~watch-marketing`

The additional qualifiers in the filename may be required to distinguish files with same scale and idiom suffixes but different size (e.g. `83.5@2x~ipad` and `76@2x~ipad`).

Example of possible drag and drop acceptable filenames with minimally required qualifiers is below.

**iOS**

```
// App Icons

app-icon@2x.png // iPhone | 60pt x 60pt | actual size: 120px x 120px

app-icon@3x.png // iPhone | 60pt x 60pt | actual size: 180px x 180px

app-icon~ipad.png // iPad | 76pt x 76pt | actual size: 76px x 76px

app-icon@2x~ipad.png // iPad | 76pt x 76pt | actual size: 152px x 152px

app-icon-83.5@2x~ipad.png // iPad Pro | 83.5pt x 83.5pt | actual size: 167px x 167px 

// Notification Icons

app-icon-20~ipad.png // iPad | 20pt x 20pt | actual size: 20px x 20px 

app-icon-20@2x~ipad.png // iPad | 20pt x 20pt | actual size: 40px x 40px 

app-icon-20@2x.png // iPhone | 20pt x 20pt | actual size: 40px x 40px 

app-icon-20@3x.png // iPhone | 20pt x 20pt | actual size: 60px x 60px 

// Settings Icons

app-icon-29.png // iPhone | 29pt x 29pt | actual size: 29px x 29px     

app-icon-29~ipad.png // iPad | 29pt x 29pt | actual size: 29px x 29px 

app-icon-29@2x~ipad.png // iPad | 29pt x 29pt | actual size: 58px x 58px

app-icon-29@2x.png // iPhone | 29pt x 29pt | actual size: 58px x 58px

app-icon-29@3x.png // iPhone | 29pt x 29pt | actual size: 87px x 87px

// Spotlight Icons

app-icon-40~ipad.png // iPad | 40pt x 40pt | actual size: 40px x 40px 

app-icon-40@2x~ipad.png // iPad | 40pt x 40pt | actual size: 80px x 80px 

app-icon-40@2x.png // iPhone | 40pt x 40pt | actual size: 80px x 80px 

app-icon-40@3x.png // iPhone | 40pt x 40pt | actual size: 120px x 120px 

// App Store

app-icon~ios-marketing.png // 1024pt x 1024pt | actual size: 1024px x 1024px
```

**Mac**

```
app-icon~mac.png // actual size: 16px x 16px

app-icon-16@2x~mac.png // actual size: 32px x 32px

app-icon-32~mac.png // actual size: 32px x 32px

app-icon-32@2x~mac.png // actual size: 64px x 64px

app-icon-128~mac.png // actual size: 128px x 128px

app-icon-128@2x~mac.png // actual size: 256px x 256px

app-icon-256~mac.png // actual size: 256px x 256px

app-icon-256@2x~mac.png // actual size: 512px x 512px

app-icon-512~mac.png // actual size: 512px x 512px

app-icon-512@2x~mac.png // actual size: 1024px x 1024px | also used for Mac App Store
```

**CarPlay**

```
app-icon@2x~car.png // 60pt x 60pt | actual size: 120px x 120px

app-icon@3x~car.png // 60pt x 60pt | actual size: 180px x 180px
```

**Apple Watch**

The correct format for qualifying roles (e.g. `Companion Settings` or `Quick Look`) and subtypes (`38 mm`, `42 mm`) was not found. So the only acceptable file here is the one for App Store.

```
app_icon~watch-marketing.png // 1024pt x 1024pt | actual size: 1024px x 1024px
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work automatically. Unless the Contents.JSON file has the "filename" param set for a particular icon, Xcode won't pickup my icon.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I have created an ["AppIcons.command"](https://gist.github.com/pd95/f8afdeb6139d96019bd60b11a70d6367) script to automatically convert the artwork into the various downscaled iPhone and iPad. My script can be executed on plain Mac OS without additional installs (thanks to `sips`). I hope this is useful to others too.

Comment: excellent summary