# Why do my alternate icons work on iPhone but not on iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I build and deploy to an iPhone, I can call `UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName` just fine. When I run on an iPad Pro, I get the following error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1c0857700 {Error Domain=LSApplicationWorkspaceErrorDomain Code=-105 "iconName not found in CFBundleAlternateIcons entry" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=iconName not found in CFBundleAlternateIcons entry}}}

Using the following code:

```
UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName(icons[indexPath.row].name) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Woops ! \(String(describing: err))")
            }
        }
```

I have standard, 2x, and 3x versions of each icon ranging from 60x60, 120x120, and 180x180. These images are placed loosely in the project, not in an assets bundle.They are referenced in my Info.plist.

What is going on? Why is there a difference between iPhone and iPad?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing alternate icon for iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949430/changing-alternate-icon-for-ipad)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to add images for the ipad resolutions too. And they're name must be something like `icon@2x~ipad.png`. That `~ipad` is the difference

The sizes for ipad are

```
iPad Pro        167px × 167px (83.5pt × 83.5pt @2x)
iPad, iPad mini 152px × 152px (76pt × 76pt @2x)
```

Comment: Almost there, you got me on the right path though. I needed a second copy of the CFBundleIcons, with the ~ipad suffix. Thank you! Sorry I accidentally deleted your comment earlier. The buttons were so small and I was a bit too fidgety.

Comment: Yeah, that's write. I forgot it. That necessary setup is a little bit confusing and I never used this feature myself. No problems with the deleted comment

Comment: @austintt would you check this Q ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949430/changing-alternate-icon-for-ipad/52015354#52015354

Comment: What naming for supporting all iPads?

Comment: If @2x are required for iPad (152px) and iPad Pro (167px), then what's the correct naming convention? For example, I have 'blueAppIcon@2x~ipad.png' as a loose file in my project (that is 152px), but if I want to add another file for iPad Pro, what should it be called?

Comment: Ok, naming is same as iPhone. Just dupe the CFBundleIcons (and name the dupe `CFBundleIcons~ipad`) tree. Of course, if you actually want different qualities for different screen sizes, you can name the different sizes differently and edit the dupe tree.

Comment: It isn't clear what the exact names and sizes should be in order to support all devices.

Comment: For iPad pro use: AppIcon-Pink-83.5@2x. More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341607/what-is-the-correct-app-icon-appicon-naming-convention-for-xcode-9-2

Answer (score 15):

A separate CFBundleIcons entry in Info.plist is needed specifically for the iPad. It must be named **CFBundleIcons~ipad**. Just copy your current CFBundleIcons entry and rename it.

Comment: I think this is a better answer because you don't need duplicate images

Comment: I can confirm this is the correct answer, as you don't need to have duplicate images.

Answer (score 4):

[image]Please do following setting to plist for setting alternate icon for ihone andiPad

Answer (score 2):

With Xcode 13+ no need to work with files/plist manually anymore.
You just need to set to **YES** the “**Include All App Icon Assets**” setting under build settings. Or click on "Your Target" - General - App Icons and Launch Screen - Include All App Icon Assets.

[image: Include app icon assets]

After that just add icons to xcassets catalog. (For some reason it doesn't always work on iPad with a Single Size icons, so you should better use Icon Set with all icon sizes).

Better **avoid using symbols** in the name of icons.
It didn't work for me on iPad with icon name "**Icon-Red**", but it worked fine with "**IconRed**"

Swift sample

```
UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName("IconRed", completionHandler: nil)
```

Obj-C sample

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setAlternateIconName:@"IconRed" completionHandler:nil];
```